# How to stop the drop cap appearing in successive paragraphs?

Tags: lettrine, drop-cap

I am writing a thesis, and having a drop cap in the first paragraph of a starting chapter looks appealing. I am using a template for the thesis I found in Overleaf, using the `lettrine` package for the drop cap. The drop cap for the first paragraph is properly aligned. However, the indentation appears in successive paragraphs as well. It would be of great help to stop this appearing in different paragraphs.

The code:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{3pt}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{2} 
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\fontfamily{ptm}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction} % Main chapter title

\label{Chapter1}
\doublespacing
%\lhead{Chapter 1. \emph{Introduction}}
%%%%-------------------Fancy Head & Footer---------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Chapter 1. \emph{Introduction}}
%%%%-------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%-------------
% Change X to a consecutive number; this is for the header on each page - perhaps a shortened title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Background}
\begin{justify}

\lettrine[loversize=0.15]{M}{emory} devices came a long way starting from punched cards in 1890 A.D. which could hold approximately 80 B (Bytes) of data, to the present day greater than 2 TB (Terabyte) memory space in USB flash drives. In the present era of the Internet of Things (IoT), people are surrounded by different sensory devices in their daily lives. These devices generate enormous amounts of data giving rise to the concept of BIG DATA in IoT \cite{Ch1_ref1}. For efficient management of such data, the requirement of an intelligent computing architecture having reliable and high-density data storage memory devices for faster and reliable data processing is of immense importance for the current and upcoming future generations \cite{Ch1_ref2}.

Currently, the memory market is dominated by DRAM and flash memory devices. To meet the growing demand in terms of read/write speed and integration density, devices are scaled aggressively, which sets limits \cite{Ch1_ref3,Ch1_ref4,Ch1_ref5} to the above devices. 2D NAND devices have been scaled down to a 15 nm technology node, further scaling sets several limitations on the device. Vertical NAND (V-NAND) or 3D NAND with a stacked structure addresses this scalability issue \cite{Ch1_ref6} and provides greater storage density. However, such devices suffer from low read-write cycles and costly fabrication methodology, making them unsuitable for applications requiring faster data processing at affordable pricing.

\end{justify}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

They have use the following command to stop the lettering package in successive paragraphs:

```
%********STOP LETTERING PACKAGE****************%
\section*{}
\parshape=0
\vspace{-25mm}
%***********************************************%
```

Any other options to stop the lettrine package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Try getting rid of `\begin{justify}` (and, presumably, `\end{justify}`, someplace later in the document).

Comment: @Mico It worked!! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's query was solved in a comment.

Comment: @Mico Can you please convert your comment into an answer. Closing questions because the answer is hidden in a comment is not good for Q&A systems, because user may think, that closed questions without answers are unanswered and also answers as answers are complicated.

Comment: @cabohah - Thanks. Ordinarily, I would be happy to post a brief answer to elaborate on my initial comment. However, because the OP has failed to indicate which document class is in use and which packages have to be loaded (in addition to the `lettrine` package) in order to make the code snippet compilable -- I'm guessing the `setspace`, `fancyhdr` and `ragged2e` packages must be loaded, but there may be others -- I thought any standalone compilable answer might mainly create further issues. Of course, you are welcome to provide an answer of your own.

Comment: @Mico Voting to close the question and at the same time welcoming me to answer the question is somehow a paradox, isn't it?

Comment: You're doing wrong in several places. There should be no need to redeclare `\doublespacing` nor to set manually the page headers and footers at every chapter. And justification is the normal setup in LaTeX, so why using `justify` at all?

Comment: @cabohah - I see no paradox. I've stated my reasons for deciding against providing a standalone answer. Natually, you're perfectly free to disagree with me and to conclude that posting an answer is worth your time.

Comment: @Mico Please read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8775/277964.

Comment: @cabohah - This is clearly a topic you feel passionate about. Good news: You are entirely free to post an answer yourself. I've given you my reasons for *not* posting an answer, and I don't see my reasons invalidated by anything in the Meta posting you've provided a link to.

Comment: @Mico I've started to do so, but then the question was closed and my answer was lost. :(

Comment: @cabohah It's all yours ;).

Answer (score 3):

As @egreg told in a comment, you should not redefine the page header for each chapter. Instead, you should use LaTeX's mark mechanism to setup the automatic marks and use them in the page header.

Using `\doublespacing` several times should also not be needed. In the example below, I just use `setspace`'s option `doublespacing` for the whole document. If you want some parts, e.g., the table of contents, don't use double spacing, it could indeed make sense, to switch between `\singlespacing` and `\doublespacing` sometimes. But in this case, it would be ideal, to do appropriate configurations in the preamble.

Last but not least, you should not need to use `\begin{justify}…\end{justifiy}` for the whole document or chapters. Justifying is the default of LaTeX, so it should not be needed at all. Instead of using this environment to justify text, you should limit not to use justifying, e.g., using a group or environment. Removing the `justify` environment also solves your problem. Now, only the usual paragraph indent is used. If you also don't want the default paragraph indent, see for example [package `parskip`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) for alternatives.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{3pt}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{2} 
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\fontfamily{ptm}}

% Define the page style once and use automatic marks
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\ifnum\c@chapter>\z@ \@chapapp~\thechapter. \fi\textit{#1}}{}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction} % Main chapter title

\label{Chapter1}
%\doublespacing

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Background}

\lettrine[loversize=0.15]{M}{emory} devices came a long way starting from punched cards in 1890 A.D. which could hold approximately 80 B (Bytes) of data, to the present day greater than 2 TB (Terabyte) memory space in USB flash drives. In the present era of the Internet of Things (IoT), people are surrounded by different sensory devices in their daily lives. These devices generate enormous amounts of data giving rise to the concept of BIG DATA in IoT \cite{Ch1_ref1}. For efficient management of such data, the requirement of an intelligent computing architecture having reliable and high-density data storage memory devices for faster and reliable data processing is of immense importance for the current and upcoming future generations \cite{Ch1_ref2}.

Currently, the memory market is dominated by DRAM and flash memory devices. To meet the growing demand in terms of read/write speed and integration density, devices are scaled aggressively, which sets limits \cite{Ch1_ref3,Ch1_ref4,Ch1_ref5} to the above devices. 2D NAND devices have been scaled down to a 15 nm technology node, further scaling sets several limitations on the device. Vertical NAND (V-NAND) or 3D NAND with a stacked structure addresses this scalability issue \cite{Ch1_ref6} and provides greater storage density. However, such devices suffer from low read-write cycles and costly fabrication methodology, making them unsuitable for applications requiring faster data processing at affordable pricing.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for highlighting this, using \doublespacing in the preamble works!!. Thank you again for vividly explaining.